# Best choice for controlling GPIOs (published messages or service calls)

Tags: control, ros, message, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Sorry if this is an already answered question, but despite a couple of hours spent googling the Web and searching in this forum, I couldn't find.

What is the rule of thumb for deciding if some control operation should be implemented using published messages or service calls ?

For controlling robot moves, I could see that the standard way is to use `Twist` messages published on the `/cmd_vel` topic. But what about controlling GPIOs for instance ? Should this be using published messages too or service calls ?

Since there is no feedback when using messages (you can't know if somebody heard them and process them), I would be tempted to use service calls instead.

Thanks in advance for any advice. Best regards.
Eric

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200838/best-choice-for-controlling-gpios-(published-messages-or-service-calls)/) by [epascual](https://answers.ros.org/users/20673/epascual/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best choice is going to depend on your particular application.

A few rules of thumb:

- If you need to guarantee that the other node got the message, use a service
- If you need a response, use a service (or an [action](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib))
- If you need speed, use a topic
- If you don't care if every message goes through, use a topic
- If you are interacting with some existing topic/service API, use whatever that API already uses

Note that it also doesn't have to be one or the other. Some nodes (such as [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base)) provide both a topic and action API for the same thing.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [epascual](https://answers.ros.org/users/20673/epascual/) on 2015-01-13**:
Thanks Dan for you quick reply. You confirm what I had concluded from studying existing material. The very last point was also something I had in mind. Regards.